# Exception during singly linked list creation

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm having trouble making a singly linked list. This linked list should receive 
name, GPA, key --- generate nodes --- print --- de-allocate memory. However, it seems like there are errors in my code. But I can't find where they are. Could you tell me where the wrong code is if you find it?

unprocessed win32 exception error occurs whenever I input name, GPA, and key information for the second node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct STUDENT {
    char name[20];
    float GPA;
    int key;
    struct STUDENT *next;
};

void newnode(struct STUDENT *head, struct STUDENT *tail, struct STUDENT *preptr, struct STUDENT *curptr, int i)
{
    struct STUDENT *newitem;

    newitem = (struct STUDENT*)malloc(sizeof(struct STUDENT));
    if (newitem == (struct STUDENT*)NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory space available");
    }

    printf("Name?\n");
    gets(newitem->name);
    getchar();
    printf("GPA?\n");
    scanf("%f", &(newitem->GPA));
    getchar();
    printf("Key?\n");
    scanf("%d", &(newitem->key));
    getchar();

    if (i == 0)
    {
        head = newitem;
        tail = newitem;
        curptr = newitem;
    }
    else
    {
        preptr = curptr;
        tail = newitem;
        curptr = newitem;
        preptr->next = newitem;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    struct STUDENT *head = NULL; //location of the first node
    struct STUDENT *tail = NULL; //location of the last node
    struct STUDENT *preptr = NULL; //previous
    struct STUDENT *curptr = NULL; //current

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        newnode(head, tail, preptr, curptr, i);
    }
    curptr = head;
    printf("name %s, GPA %f, key %d\n", curptr->name, curptr->GPA, curptr->key);
    preptr = head;
    curptr = curptr->next;

    for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        printf("name %s, GPA %f, key %d\n", curptr->name, curptr->GPA, curptr->key);
        curptr = curptr->next;
    }

    curptr = head;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        free(curptr);
        curptr = curptr->next;
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Your assignments to curptr, preptr etc in your newnode method are discarded as soon as that method returns. Try adding '&' to the parameters, making them references. Have a nice weekend too!

Comment: The title of this question is not specific. Anybody with the same problem in the future will not be able to find it.

Comment: As kenndy said, your pointers head, tail, ... are passed by values, you are changing their values inside the newnode function, but the change remain local. If you only have a C compiler you should should pass **head **tail, ... and write *head=newnode, *tail=newnode, ....

Comment: Thank you for all of your advices! And I will take care of the title and tags next time, sorry;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `void newnode(struct STUDENT *head, struct STUDENT *tail, struct STUDENT *preptr, struct STUDENT *curptr, int i)` you are allocating and modifying the content of the pointers (or at least you hope they are updated) but in that case you need to pass pointer to `head`, `tail`, `preptr` and `curptr` because you want that these variables in the `main()` will be updated.

So change the signature of `newnode` to

```
void newnode(struct STUDENT **head, struct STUDENT **tail, struct STUDENT **preptr, struct STUDENT **curptr, int i)
```

and the content of that function accordingly:

```
    if (i == 0)
    {
        *head = newitem;
        *tail = newitem;
        *curptr = newitem;
    }
    else
    {
        *preptr = *curptr;
        *tail = newitem;
        *curptr = newitem;
        (*preptr)->next = newitem;
    }
```

And call for this function accordingly:

```
newnode(&head, &tail, &preptr, &curptr, i);
```

Few general tips:

```
newitem = (struct STUDENT*)malloc(sizeof(struct STUDENT));
```

There is no need to cast the returned value of malloc snce it returns `void *` which is assignable to any kind of pointer.

```
if (newitem == (struct STUDENT*)NULL)
```

Same thing here. No need to cast `NULL`.

```
if (newitem == (struct STUDENT*)NULL)
{
    printf("No memory space available");
}
```

Once you detected that there is a problem with memory allocation, you better return from that function after printing the error message. Otherwise your code will keep on running inside that function accessing struct fields which were not allocated.

```
gets(newitem->name);
```

It is not safe to use `gets` since your buffer (`name`) is limited to 20 but if `gets` will get a string of 100 chars it will store them all in `name` overriding everything that is beyond `name` memory causing undefined behavior.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    free(curptr);
    curptr = curptr->next;
}
```

This code is incorrect. since you first free `curptr` and then access its field. You should first save `curptr->next` in some temporal variable `temp = curptr->next`, then free `curptr` and then reassigng it `curptr = temp;`